# PHP replace urls with Anchor text

Tags: php, regex, dom, replace

```
$x = 'A fox was <a href="/xyz/dancingwith">Dancing with</a> light. The night <a href="/xyz/treeare">tree are</a> growing.';

I want to become this

$x = 'A fox was <a href="/xyz/dancing-with">Dancing with</a> light. The night <a href="/xyz/tree-are">tree are</a> growing.';
```

i want to replace all

```
<a href="xyz">x y z</a> to <a href="x-y-z">x y z</a>
```

or

```
<a href="xaybzc">xA yB zC</a> to <a href="xa-yb-zc">xA yB zC</a>
```

I want to become this

Please Help me.

Comment: Could you show us what you've tried that didn't work ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php

$x = 'A fox was <a href="/xyz/dancingwith">Dancing with</a> light. The night <a href="/xyz/treeare">tree are</a> growing.';

$doc = new DOMDocument;
$doc->loadHTML($x);
$anchors = $doc->getElementsByTagName('a');
$len = $anchors->length;
for($i = 0; $i < $len; $i++) {
    $newPath = preg_replace('/\s+/', '-',strtolower($anchors->item($i)->nodeValue));
    $oldHref = $anchors->item($i)->getAttribute('href');
    $url = explode('/', $oldHref);
    array_pop($url);
    array_push($url, $newPath);
    $newUrl = implode('/', $url);


        $anchors->item($i)->setAttribute('href', $newUrl);

}
$newHTML = $doc->saveHTML();
echo $newHTML;
```

Comment: @DavidCorp please try my new answer.

Comment: @DavidCorp It is good and can you please up vote my answer? :)

Comment: `$len = $anchors->length; for($i = 0; $i < $len; $i++) {`: instead use a foreach loop: `foreach ($anchors as $anchor) {`